# Windows 7 System File Checker (sfc) not working

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have a strange problem with Windows 7 RTM.  I'm running Ultimate 64-bit edition.

Whenever I run `sfc /scannow` I get this error:

```
Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.
```

My research so far has told me that I need to set the `Windows Module Installer` and `Windows Installer` services' startup types to `Manual`.

They already were, so I manually started those services and tried again.  No luck.

I've even booted into my Windows 7 repair disc and tried running `sfc /scannow` from that.  All I get is this:

```
A repair operation is already pending.  Restart and try again.
```

**History**:

I'm trying to run sfc because I am unable to open any images in `Windows Photo Viewer`.  Whenever I try, I get the error "`Class not registered`."

I believe the problem started after I installed [Gladinet](http://www.gladinet.com/), but I can't be sure.  I've uninstalled Gladinet, but the problem remains.

System Restore was disabled (yes, I know I'm stupid - you don't have to remind me).  Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at the event log? It usually has much better information about things like this. You might even be able to get the actual class's CLSID which needs to be registered. But at this point it sounds like the system is far gone enough that it should be formatted and reinstalled as a matter of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing helped.  I ended up having to re-install Windows 7.  A friendly reminder to everyone:

## DO NOT DISABLE SYSTEM RESTORE

At the very least, don't do it if you intend to try out beta software.